# c# serial port receive event: program is still branching the receive event when i close the port and delete event from Port.DataReceived

Tags: c#, events, serial-port

I want to disable/enable the receive without closing the port or deleting the receive handler method because they are not working or i'm doing wrong something.

I'm doing now;

```
byte[] rData = new byte[10];
public void SendData(byte[] a, int count)
{
    if (Port.IsOpen == false)
        Port.Open();
    Port.Write(a, 0, count);
    // start receive timeout timer
    Port.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(ReceiveData);
}
public void ReceiveData(object s, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    int ctrl = 0;
    int DataCnt = 5; // for example
    Port = (SerialPort)s;
    ctrl = Port.Read(rData, 0, DataCnt); // if timeout haven't finished yet
    if (ctrl != DataCnt)
    { /* set receive error flag */ }
    else
    {
        Port.DiscardInBuffer();
        if (Port.IsOpen == true)
            Port.Close();
        Port.DataReceived -= new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(ReceiveData);
        // set receive complete flag
    }
}
```

I'm getting the bytes correctly but when the program branches the `else` block of the `ReceiveData`, I'm discarding input buffer, closing the port if it is open, and deleting the receive event hander but it's again branching in the `ReceiveData` and naturally `InvalidOperationException` event is occuring because I've closed the port. Why the program is branching again the receive event after delete the event from `Port.DataReceived`? I'm using Windows 8.1 pro and visual studio 2010 pro. Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried to unsubscribe before closing the port?

Comment: Thank you @DmitryDovgopoly Do you mean; `Port.DataReceived -= new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(ReceiveData);` before `Port.Close();` ? if you mean that yes i've tried but still same

Comment: There are *way* too many bugs in this code to guess what might happen.  Work from existing code snippets from MSDN or google queries to have a shot at getting this right.

Comment: I've found [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2006/10/10/top-5-serialport-tips-_5b00_kim-hamilton_5d00_.aspx) link which is about the top 5 serial port tips and talking about closing the port at the 3rd tip but `Invoke` or `BeginInvoke` methods aren't availible under `this` or `Port`.

Comment: thank you @HansPassant. But i didn't understand why there are too many bugs in my code. I deleted the `Port = (SerialPort)s;` and `if (Port.IsOpen == true) { Port.Close() }` and added `Form.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false;` at below the `int DataCnt = 0;` and `Form.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = true;` at the bottom of the `ReceiveData` event it's working true and not branching into the event after unsubscribe the event from handler. But is it true I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

my advice would be to not mess about with the port inside your data received event handler. You don't know what the port does after calling your handler (or what other event handlers subscribed to the same event might do) and it may not expect to be closed when you return, which could cause "undefined behavior"

Instead, set a flag to indicate that you have received all the data and are ready to close the port, and get your main program loop to actually close it at some point in the future. (you can also ignore any extra calls to your data received event handler once you have the information you need)

After unsubscribing an event handler you can still get calls to your handler if another thread was in the process of calling the  handlers at the moment you unsubscribed. So to avoid race conditions it is better to handle additional calls gracefully than rely on unsubscribing during event handling. This is unlikely, but where threading is concerned, "unlikely" usually happens quite often!

A good rule of thumb to remember for event handlers is to do as little work as possible while you are handling the event. Record what you need to know and defer all other processing to another thread so you can return quickly to the caller.

Comment: Thank you @Jason-Williams i've also deleted the port closing method but unsubscriber still in the handler but i did some changes in the handler as i state at the above comment. I don't really want to open or close the port any state of my program just want to enable / disable Rx or Tx but there is no property or method at the SerialPort class about that and i don't go to the low level with C#. I'll try your advice but now i need to do test communicate between pc and embedded device which is i designed. After the communication is working well i'll change some states of my pc program.ThanksAgain

Comment: Just to clarify, to stop Rx/Tx you must close the port.